# Paypal REST API - Error on Capture PAYER_CANNOT_PAY

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

We have deployed successfully Paypal on our website. However, every now and then, we get an error when a customer tries to pay.

Here is the error:

{"name":"PAYER_CANNOT_PAY","message":"The combination of payer and payee settings mean that this buyer can't pay this seller.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#PAYER_CANNOT_PAY","debug_id":"fb74a83818f40"}

Unfortunately Paypal's documentation doesn't say much. I also find this error very strange given it happens at the CAPTURE, after EXECUTE and after Paypal reports back to us with a success.

The payments show up in our Paypal account as Pending.

How do I resolve this? Does anyone know what causes this? So far I am unable to see what can cause this or reproduce it in my tests.

Here are the steps taken:

1 - We create a payment object using the REST API and redirect the user to the Approval link

2 - The customer goes to paypal and enters the desired payment information

3 - Our success return URL gets called after the customer completes everythin on the paypal side

4 - We execute the payment

5 - We capture the payment  <-- ERROR happens HERE

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's buyer's funding source issue, payment is declined by buyer's card bank. it's not your integration issue. Buyer need to call bank to fix his/her card, then you try to capture the money again.